# Syntax of fadeIn,fadeOut

Tags: jquery

I cannot find the right syntax for applying fadeIn, fadeOut to the the following:

```
 $( "#first" ).hover(
   function() {
       $("#first").css("background-color","#171716" );     

      },
   function() {
       $("#first").css("background-color","#FAFAF8" );         
      }
   );
```

as to achieve smooth change-transition in the background color of the div  "first".
Thank you

Comment: [fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) and [fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not fade in/out, you need to use [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) - to animate background color you need to use [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)/[jQuery color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color/)

```
$("#first").hover(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        "background-color": "#171716"
    });
}, function () {
    $(this).animate({
        "background-color": "#FAFAF8"
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/U8LkR/)

Comment: In your demo color is not being applied propery

Answer (score 1):

The pure jQuery does not have functionality to animate colors. You have to use [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com) or [jQuery color plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color). And then use `.animate()`.